# Submit an array of objects as a query variable in graphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

How can I structure the query parameters a graphQL mutation when one of the fields is an array of objects? When I hard-code the mutation this is valid and works:

```
mutation{
  submitResponse(user: "1234", responses: [{ answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBe", selected: false}, { answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBz", selected: true}]) {
    id
  }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass in query parameters for the responses array of objects. How can I define the type of each field in the object. This is what it would like for the user id and that works fine but I can't figure out the responses piece of it.

```
mutation submitResponse($user: ID!){
  submitResponse(user: $user, responses: [{ answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBe", selected: false}, { answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBz", selected: true}]) {
    id
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is old, but maybe someone else needs simple solution.

1. Set type of `responses` as `String!`

   ```
   mutation submitResponse($user: ID!, $responses: String!){
     submitResponse(user: $user, responses: $responses) {
       id
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
   yourData = [{ answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBe", selected: false}, { answerId: "wmtBCWtkSeDs5meBz", selected: true}]
   responses = JSON.stringify(yourData)
   ```
3. In my case in BackEnd I use Python, so receive `responses` in BackEnd and then simply convert JSON (string) to Python's dict, something like:

   ```
   import json
   responses = json.loads(input.get('responses'))
   ```