# GraphQL: How to create a query with a curated list of parameters (a 2D array)

Tags: arrays, graphql, relaymodern

Specifically I feel like I am looking for the answer to the question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910230/submit-an-array-of-objects-as-a-query-variable-in-graphql), but it turns out the title of the question isn't a perfect match for the actual question.

What I am looking to do involves Relay, React, and GraphQL (I suppose I could have stated Relay, and you could have figured out the other two).

What I want to do, and what I can't seem to find an answer to, is to create a query that lists a variable list of query fragments based on some predefined JSON array.

If you look at my home page, [jimmyvanveen.com](http://www.jimmyvanveen.com) you will see I have a list of projects I have worked on (or am working on), and each renders as a React component. I am pulling this data from Github through their REST API (v3) - but now I want to migrate to GraphQL (v4).

I can make an array containing the repo name, and owner as required by the Schema of Github's API, but I don't know how to dynamically create a query based off a simple array such as:

```
repos: [
  {"name": "repo name", "owner": "Repo Owner"},
  {"name": "other repo", "ownder": "Other Owner"}
]
```

I know how to make a query that can find all of this information manually, but I was hoping there was a GraphQL way (perhaps by sending vars?) to run through the entire array in one query and return the array of repo data.

I've been racking my brain for days trying to find the answer here, or anywhere, and I'm striking out.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: FYI I've learned that it's basically impossible to do what I want. This annoys me, but I accept it since this is how GraphQL works, I just cannot send a 2D array to a query.

I ended up stumbling upon what I think is a better solution, and you can see how I implement this in my [repo on Github](https://github.com/JimmayVV/JimmyVanVeen.com/tree/e82798ad0b8b8d4d8d588467b80e20118a148a51).

I am leaving this question open in case someone else has an answer I haven't thought of, but in general I've given up hope :)

Thanks!
Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I figured out I am in general just submitting the wrong information to Github in order to pull Repo info from a curated list.

My objective above is still not possible exactly the way I wanted to solve the problem, however the method mentioned above is very similar to a usable method that DOES work. Simply put, supply Github with an array of unique node ID's, rather than Repo Name and Repo Owner, as I had been trying to do.

This way, you are not trying to use a 2D array, and instead you are using a single array, with an equal amount of specificity as the 2D array.

So formulating an array such as:

```
const repos = [
  'uniqueID1',
  'uniqueID2',
  'uniqueID3',
  ...
];
```

...can then be passed through Relay (I had the QueryRenderer set to run on my App component) like so:

```
query AppQuery($repos:[ID!]!) {
   projects: nodes(ids:$repos){
     ...projects_projects
   }
 }
```

You can obtain the node ID's in multiple ways, but the way I did this was by pulling the repo info one by one in GraphiQL with a query such as this:

```
query { 
  repository(owner:"JimmayVV", name:"JimmyVanVeen.com") {
    id
  }
}
```

I then consolidated all of these ID's into an array, and passed that through to Relay and got the desired results.

I'm sure there are other ways, perhaps using a simple Node script to formulate the array for you, but this was simple enough for me, that I am happy with it.